# How to group members with template specializations in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a template class which contains two member functions. After the class declaration, I provide explicit template specialization for the member function foo.

I have the following doxygen configuration options and use doxygen 1.9.5:

```
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = NO
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
```

Here is the source code,

```
/**
* Example class
*/
template<typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        /**
        * Member function 1
        */
        T foo(T a);

        /**
        * Member function 2
        */
        void print();
};

/**
* Template specialization of member function foo
*/
template<>
double A<double>::foo(double a)
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

and the corresponding html output

[image]

As you can see, the function documentation appears in the order of declaration.
What I want is that the overloads are grouped although the overload for `foo` is defined outside the class. In particular, `foo() [1/2]` should be followed by `foo() [2/2]` and the print function at the end, both in the member function documentation and in the listing of public member functions.

How can I do that with the given options to not sort members? I want to keep them because I have a bunch of other classes where I do not want sorting.

Comment: its a little confusing that `doxygen` which is what the quesiton is about only appears in the tags (and a side note at the very end). I was reading the beginning twice and got confused before understanding what the quesiton is actually about.  Use tags to categorize the quesiton, not as only place for important information.

Comment: and please include also the code used to generate the docs. A [mcve]

Comment: _"After the class declaration"_ you meant "definition", right?

Comment: The current doxygen version is 1.9.8, what happens with the current version?

Comment: @albert I can only use 1.9.5 at the moment.

Comment: Well the example is more important (and maybe an image to show what you want to accomplish). Having the example i is possible to do some experiments (with different versions).

Comment: @albert I added an minimal example and the html output associated with it. Is it clear what I want to do?

Comment: Doxygen got group concept, but you need additional comment blocks for that https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Thanks for pointing to this. But how can I use a member group block `///@{ ... ///@}` in my case, given that the template specialization for foo is not underneath the corresponding member definition?

Comment: @Simon Supposed to be purpose of `\ingroup` tag but I never tested it with templates. template support is relatively new and finicky. Youalso can nest groups by that and there is a a way to "borrow" documentation from another entity.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Do you have a particular solution for my problem?

Comment: I saw source and image, the result looks a bit unexpected. The result is due to the setting of `SORT_MEMBER_DOCS` when setting it to `YES` the functions are grouped, but still the order is a bit strange as in the mentioned case one would like to have the  member function first and afterwards the specialization thought this is not the case. So probably the `SORT_MEMBER_DOCS` setting needs some extra possibilities where specialization functions are shown after the function (best is to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues, so it won''t get lost)

Comment: @albert So you also do not see a solution with the current doxygen (or 1.9.5)?

Comment: No not really (nor with the current doxygen1.9.8 version) you could do some tricks with `\defgroup` / `\ingroup` but this would probably lead to that the other functions are documented at another place than the specific templated functions and in the groups you probably wouldn't get the order right either.